# Variable alternates whether or not it exists in Python Debugger

Tags: python, django, pdb

Can anyone explain this? (Python 2.7, Django 1.7)

```
foo = data['selected_items']
(Pdb) foo
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
foo
(Pdb) u'1,2'
foo
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
foo
(Pdb) u'1,2'
foo
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
foo
(Pdb) u'1,2'
```

Here is the view function that triggered it:

```
def process_form(request, model_name):
    form = BulkEditForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.clean()

        if data['select_all']:
            pass
        else:
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

request.POST:

```
{'select_all': False, 'primary_tech': <Person: Bob>, 'primary_biz': <Person: Mary>, 'selected_items': u'1,2', 'backup_tech': None, 'backup_biz': None}
```

Comment: can you give us more context.

Comment: There's not a whole lot more to give.  I added the request.POST, but I don't know that it gives more information.  Is there something specific I should add?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but do you know [`pudb`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb)? It has a nice UI for debugging, so it might be easier to debug than using `pdb`.

Comment: FWIW, my code seems to have healed itself.  I can't recreate the error (although it happened a few times in a row).  I'm still curious as to what happened, though, if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two threads which stopped at the same breakpoint.

So basically, there are two instances of pdb, competing for your prompt, i.e. your prompts are alternating between the different threads. You first assign to the name `foo` in one, than the other one gets a chance to run, knowing nothing about `foo`, then when you press enter, the other is back, with `foo` defined.

The best indicator that this is the case is that your prompt is not aligned with your commands and their outputs. Instead of:

```
<PROMPT> COMMAND
OUTPUT
<PROMPT> COMMAND
OUTPUT
```

You see:

```
COMMAND
<PROMPT> OUTPUT
COMMAND
<PROMPT> OUTPUT
```

Everytime you press enter, the "other" thread sneaks in its prompt before the "first" thread manages to write its output.

---

EDIT

A simple way to reproduce in a standalone, without django:

```
from threading import Thread

def f(x):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    while True: pass

t1 = Thread(target=lambda: f(1))
t2 = Thread(target=lambda: f(2))
t1.start(); t2.start()

(Pdb) x
2
(Pdb) x
1
```

Comment: Do you know what could have caused this?  I'd like to recreate it and test it; it disappeared on its own.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What could have caused more than one thread to run? to reach the same function where you placed your breakpoint? Even without using django, you can write a script which starts two threads calling the same function, and place a breakpoint in it.

Answer (score 0):

When the statement appears in PDB, it hasn't actually been executed yet. It will be executed once you use 'next'.

Comment: I typed that in myself to the debugger.  It wasn't from my code base.  My code had a more complex version, chaining a few things together, so I was trying to break it down to figure out where my (different) error was.