# PDB inconsistently recognizing variables

Tags: python, django, pdb

```
foo
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
foo = 'foo'
(Pdb) print(foo)
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
foo
(Pdb) 27
```

(note:  in a previous pdb session, I defined foo as 27)

Continuing:

```
foo = "foo"
(Pdb) foo
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
print(foo)
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
foo
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
foo
(Pdb) 'foo'
foo
(Pdb) *** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Comment: [A very similar quetion was asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25146489/2096752) 6 months ago, and was answered correctly, and in details. Unfortunately, the poster did not appreciate the effort put into answering his question, and did not accept nor upvote the answer, nor any of the other answers. Now the same user posts this question again... Will you be so kind as to accept/upvote an answer not posted by yourself?

Comment: Wow... I duplicated my own question.  That's new.  My humble apologies--I didn't even remember experiencing this problem until I saw the link.  I'm usually very good about accepting answers (I've gone back and accepted and upvoted it).  Thank you for the time and effort you put into answering me the first time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My site was running with threads on.  Running it without threading fixed the issue.

Comment: Ah, it was a web app? Out of curiosity, what framework were you using?

Comment: This is correct--incidentally, you *can* accept your own answer ;)

Comment: Not yet I can't.  Also not sure if this question is worthwhile for keeping open or too specific to my situation.